# Make infinite scrollable ImageViews

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making an app which allows a user to search the various countries. The user can make filtered searches (such as, for example, search only countries of a specific continent, etc...). All this info (Countries and their continents are stored in my Firebase Realtime Database).
In my `FilteredResults.java` fragment I want to have a variable number of ImageViews (the number of the size of a `List<String>`).
This sketch I drew might help you understand it better:

[image]

Each one of this rectangles are ImageViews. 
This is my XML (I just have a scrollview because I don't know how to create an "array" of ImageViews...)

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResultadosFiltrados"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="Resultados Filtrados"
    android:textColor="#323B45"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">





    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RecyclerView` instead of `ScrollView`. As keeping array of `ImageView` and adding them in a `ScrollView` will create a explosive headache.

Comment: Ahaha you again to save my code. How can I create an array of ImageViews depending on `paisNome.size();`?

Comment: What is paisNome?

Comment: A List<String> with all the countries retrieved by the query

Comment: Than you don't have problem just implement a RecyclerView with paisNome and it will give you a method `getcount` where you can give `paisNome.size()`. Tada you'll be good to go.

Comment: So, I declare an ImageView array like this `ImageView[] IMGS= new ImageView[paisNome.size()];` ?

Comment: No you don&#39;t require  ImageView[]. Implemting a RecyclerView will handle that. Just follow this link for implementation  https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-implement-a-recyclerview-33fd4ff9988e

Comment: Oh. I get what you're saying. By the way, do I need to create another xml with the imageview and then `<include>` it to the current xml?

Comment: No not you don't have to include that in the xml you provided. In the above xml you just need to replace `ScrollView` to `RecyclerView`. Please follow that link that will tell you how to do it.

Comment: In that webiste when it says `recyclerView.layoutmanager` what should I do?
It only appears to me `getLayoutManager` or `setLayoutManager`

Comment: setLayoutManager

Comment: And what do I put inside setLayoutManager() ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve your problem in an optimal way, you should use one of:

- a plain old [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview),
- a newer, more powerful [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

These views support so called `adapters` which map between a model (in your case: `List<String>`) and a list of items (in your case a list of `ImageView`'s).

Here you have a complete example of a simple app which loads lists of posts from the Firebase Database:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database

This example is based on `RecyclerView`s, you can find an a direct usage here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/fragment/PostListFragment.java